# How to call java web service from html contact form submit button to send email?

Tags: javascript, java, amazon-web-services

We have a contact form on Website which says "Ask for Demo". When anybody completes that form, mail should go to sales@xxxxx.com. I tried Formspree.io for getting mails but it needs confirmation everytime mail is received.
So I browse about alternate options and found that through java rest web service this can be achieved. But not clear how to call sendmail() from my html page. And what all other things would be required.

Please help. TIA

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Make an ajax call from the form submit event and send the required parameters. On the backend, send the mail accordingly.

Comment: Read more about service calls using ajax - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started